# Angular Ionic Style Change

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am developing ionic mobile app. When I write code below in scss,

```
ion-content{
     background: rgba(15, 19, 31, 0.94) no-repeat;;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
```

I can't change background of item. Because code below prevent to make it. ı cant find where it is written .

```
:host {
    --background: var(--ion-background-color,#fff);
    --color: var(--ion-text-color,#000);
    --padding-top: 0px;
    --padding-bottom: 0px;
    --padding-start: 0px;
    --padding-end: 0px;
    --keyboard-offset: 0px;
    --offset-top: 0px;
    --offset-bottom: 0px;
    --overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0!important;
    padding: 0!important;
    font-family: var(--ion-font-family,inherit);
    contain: layout size style;
}
```

How can I change background of ion-content.There is a way that writing div inside it and giving style to it. but I don't want to do this. I want to give style directly to item.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
ion-content{
     --background: rgba(15, 19, 31, 0.94) no-repeat;
}
```